# PostgreSQL filter data based on star date and end date on result column

Tags: postgresql

In above image mon_year column contain month and year data.I have start date and end date and want to filter on mon_year column.
ex.I am selecting start date is 22-06-2017 and end date 20-01-2018.So last two row will not come in result.I am using date_part PostgreSQL function but its not working.
right now I have separate column of month and year.

Comment: _Don't_ store your dates as text!  It is not worth giving you a workaround for this.  Recreate your table and store them as proper dates.

Comment: I am changing my table data which contain separate month and year column so its is possible to filter data

Comment: keep the column as date format; ex `select column1 from your_table where start_date > '2017-06-22 00:00:00.228628' and end_date < '2018-01-20 00:00:00.228628' `

Comment: You store year and month as `double precision` which (counter-intuitively, if you look at the name) is not a precise number. This is terrible and even worse than `text`.